# Solace Messaging - Payload size

Tags: messaging, solace

What is the maximum payload size that is currently supported by solace messaging platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum message size supported by Solace is 64 MB for a direct message or 30 MB for a guaranteed message when running SolOS version 7.0 or higher.